# Need to dynamically change the "Tint" video effect on Text layer, without affecting beneath footage on Adobe Premiere Pro

Tags: adobe, video-editing, adobe-premiere, video-effects

I'm using Adobe Premiere Pro 23.4.0. I have added a track with some text using the text tool, which displays on the foreground of some footage. Then I've added an Adjustment Layer on the top of the text track, where I am using the "Tint" video effect to change the aspect of the text. The problem is that this is affecting all the tracks, changing the colors of the footage too. I want to apply the Adjustment Layer only to the text.
I cannot move the track under the footage, because then the text will not appear anymore on the footage. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I randomly find out that if I **firstly Group** the text and adjustment layer, and **then choose "Nest…"**, I can take the result and place it above the footage, without affecting the other tracks.

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered, you can Nest both the adjustment layer and the text layer together, but you could also simply add a tint effect to the text layer directly.

But if you're just trying to set the text color, the correct method would be to unfold the Text property for the text layer in the Effect Controls panel (Window menu > Effect Controls) and simply change the color of the text there along with all the other usual text options.

[You can see it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4YO2.png)